# How to Detect "human hand Pose" using OpenPose or any other alternatives in python and OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, openpose

I am trying to detect human hand pose using OpenPose just like given in this video https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/.github/media/pose_face_hands.gif for hand part. I have downloaded the caffe model and prototxt file. Below is my code to implement the model.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

frame = cv2.imread("6.jpg")
frame_rgb=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(frame_rgb)

threshold = 0.025
input_width, input_height = 368, 368

nPoints = 22
POSE_PAIRS = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [0, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [0, 9],
              [9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12], [0, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16], [0, 17],
              [17, 18], [18, 19], [19, 20]]


net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe('pose_deploy_hand.prototxt', 'pose_iter_102000.caffemodel')

net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_OPENCL)
origin_h, origin_w = frame_rgb.shape[:2]
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame_rgb, 1.0 / 255, (input_width, input_height), 0, swapRB=False, crop=False)
net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()

H = detections.shape[2]
W = detections.shape[3]

points = []

for i in range(nPoints):
    probility_map = detections[0, i, :, :]
            #
    min_value, confidence, min_loc, point = cv2.minMaxLoc(probility_map)
            #
    x = int(origin_w * (point[0] / W))
    y = int(origin_h * (point[1] / H))
    if confidence > threshold:
        cv2.circle(frame_rgb, (x, y), 6, (255, 255, 0), -1, cv2.FILLED)
        #cv.putText(frame, "{}".format(i), (x, y-15), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (0, 0, 255), 1, cv.LINE_AA)
        points.append((x, y))
    else:
        points.append(None)
        
for pair in POSE_PAIRS:
    A, B = pair[0], pair[1]
    if points[A] and points[B]:
        cv2.line(frame_rgb, points[A], points[B], (0, 255, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)        
        

plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
plt.imshow(frame_rgb)
```

test Image: [image]

Output Image: [image]

I have tried different images too. But still, the output is too far away from desired.

Can you please suggest the modifications I need to do or any other alternative approach in python and openCV for detection of the hand part alone or with full body? Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below

```
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np


protoFile = "hand/pose_deploy.prototxt"
weightsFile = "hand/pose_iter_102000.caffemodel"
nPoints = 22
POSE_PAIRS = [ [0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[0,5],[5,6],[6,7],[7,8],[0,9],[9,10],[10,11],[11,12],[0,13],[13,14],[14,15],[15,16],[0,17],[17,18],[18,19],[19,20] ]

threshold = 0.2


video_file = "videoMis.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)
hasFrame, frame = cap.read()

frameWidth = frame.shape[1]
frameHeight = frame.shape[0]

aspect_ratio = frameWidth/frameHeight

inHeight = 368
inWidth = int(((aspect_ratio*inHeight)*8)//8)

vid_writer = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 15, (frame.shape[1],frame.shape[0]))

net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(protoFile, weightsFile)
k = 0
while 1:
    k+=1
    t = time.time()
    hasFrame, frame = cap.read()
    frameCopy = np.copy(frame)
    if not hasFrame:
        cv2.waitKey()
        break

    inpBlob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0 / 255, (inWidth, inHeight),
                              (0, 0, 0), swapRB=False, crop=False)

    net.setInput(inpBlob)

    output = net.forward()

    print("forward = {}".format(time.time() - t))

    # Empty list to store the detected keypoints
    points = []

    for i in range(nPoints):
        # confidence map of corresponding body's part.
        probMap = output[0, i, :, :]
        probMap = cv2.resize(probMap, (frameWidth, frameHeight))

        # Find global maxima of the probMap.
        minVal, prob, minLoc, point = cv2.minMaxLoc(probMap)

        if prob > threshold :
            cv2.circle(frameCopy, (int(point[0]), int(point[1])), 6, (0, 255, 255), thickness=-1, lineType=cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.putText(frameCopy, "{}".format(i), (int(point[0]), int(point[1])), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .8, (0, 0, 255), 2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

            # Add the point to the list if the probability is greater than the threshold
            points.append((int(point[0]), int(point[1])))
        else :
            points.append(None)

    # Draw Skeleton
    for pair in POSE_PAIRS:
        partA = pair[0]
        partB = pair[1]

        if points[partA] and points[partB]:
            cv2.line(frame, points[partA], points[partB], (0, 255, 255), 2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.circle(frame, points[partA], 5, (0, 0, 255), thickness=-1, lineType=cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.circle(frame, points[partB], 5, (0, 0, 255), thickness=-1, lineType=cv2.FILLED)

    print("Time Taken for frame = {}".format(time.time() - t))

    # cv2.putText(frame, "time taken = {:.2f} sec".format(time.time() - t), (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, .8, (255, 50, 0), 2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    # cv2.putText(frame, "Hand Pose using OpenCV", (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (255, 50, 0), 2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.imshow('Output-Skeleton', frame)
    # cv2.imwrite("video_output/{:03d}.jpg".format(k), frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

    print("total = {}".format(time.time() - t))

    vid_writer.write(frame)

vid_writer.release()
```

Code credits: https://learnopencv.com/hand-keypoint-detection-using-deep-learning-and-opencv/

For a single image, you can try the code below

```
from __future__ import division
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np

protoFile = "hand/pose_deploy.prototxt"
weightsFile = "hand/pose_iter_102000.caffemodel"
nPoints = 22
POSE_PAIRS = [ [0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[0,5],[5,6],[6,7],[7,8],[0,9],[9,10],[10,11],[11,12],[0,13],[13,14],[14,15],[15,16],[0,17],[17,18],[18,19],[19,20] ]
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(protoFile, weightsFile)

frame = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
frameCopy = np.copy(frame)
frameWidth = frame.shape[1]
frameHeight = frame.shape[0]
aspect_ratio = frameWidth/frameHeight

threshold = 0.1

t = time.time()
# input image dimensions for the network
inHeight = 368
inWidth = int(((aspect_ratio*inHeight)*8)//8)
inpBlob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0 / 255, (inWidth, inHeight), (0, 0, 0), swapRB=False, crop=False)

net.setInput(inpBlob)

output = net.forward()
print("time taken by network : {:.3f}".format(time.time() - t))

# Empty list to store the detected keypoints
points = []

for i in range(nPoints):
    # confidence map of corresponding body's part.
    probMap = output[0, i, :, :]
    probMap = cv2.resize(probMap, (frameWidth, frameHeight))

    # Find global maxima of the probMap.
    minVal, prob, minLoc, point = cv2.minMaxLoc(probMap)

    if prob > threshold :
        cv2.circle(frameCopy, (int(point[0]), int(point[1])), 8, (0, 255, 255), thickness=-1, lineType=cv2.FILLED)
        cv2.putText(frameCopy, "{}".format(i), (int(point[0]), int(point[1])), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

        # Add the point to the list if the probability is greater than the threshold
        points.append((int(point[0]), int(point[1])))
    else :
        points.append(None)

# Draw Skeleton
for pair in POSE_PAIRS:
    partA = pair[0]
    partB = pair[1]

    if points[partA] and points[partB]:
        cv2.line(frame, points[partA], points[partB], (0, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.circle(frame, points[partA], 8, (0, 0, 255), thickness=-1, lineType=cv2.FILLED)
        cv2.circle(frame, points[partB], 8, (0, 0, 255), thickness=-1, lineType=cv2.FILLED)


cv2.imshow('Output-Keypoints', frameCopy)
cv2.imshow('Output-Skeleton', frame)


cv2.imwrite('Output-Keypoints.jpg', frameCopy)
cv2.imwrite('Output-Skeleton.jpg', frame)

print("Total time taken : {:.3f}".format(time.time() - t))

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: could you please tell what is the difference between your code and my code except for I am detecting image and you are detecting in video?

Comment: Also , please tryout my code in your sample images and tell if it is working alright for you.

Comment: And i want to detect both hands in one image. what should I do for this?

Comment: I have updated the code for the image now. You can try

Comment: Yes, it worked for this case. Thank you. But I am still having a problem with the image where the hand part is very small. Could you suggest any method? Also I am detecting both the hands in the same image.

Comment: like you can try using this with [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=messi+photo&sxsrf=ALeKk00lY0lTLyzM13FRcgRzvyRYkNUtkw:1610788297188&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIhYyCjqDuAhXFF3IKHeGZCXoQ_AUoAXoECBMQAw&biw=1366&bih=568#imgrc=5ny5gchtUWzH_M) image